# String Concatenation on vTiger field before save handler on Javascript (code inside)

Tags: javascript, vtiger, vtigercrm

in vtiger 6.5 i'm trying to achieve this: in the Contact Module, when the user inputs firstname, lastname and birthday, the js code should concatenate the 3 of them and put the result in the text field cf_1142.

I put this code in layouts/vlayout/modules/Contacts/resources/Edit.js

```
createUniqueId: function (){  
    var firstname = $("input[name='firstname']");
    var lastname = $("input[name='lastname']");
    var birthday = $("input[name='birthday']");
    $(document).on('keyup',"input[name='firstname'], input[name='lastname', input[name='birthday']", function(){
      if (firstname.val() != '' && lastname.val() != ''&& birthday.val() != ''){
        var uniqueid = string.concat(firstname, lastname, birthday);
        $("input[name='cf_1142']").val(uniqueid);
      }
    })
  },
```

Then i added in the Edit.js into registerBasicEvents:

```
registerBasicEvents : function(container){
    this._super(container);
    this.registerReferenceSelectionEvent(container);
    this.registerEventForCopyingAddress(container);
    this.registerRecordPreSaveEvent(container);
    this.creaIdentificativo();
}
```

I'm a novice and i tried to adapt other code that did a math calculation to make it work with string concatenation, but it doesn't. Can someone help me in correct it and tell me what i did wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why the name of your function is not the same that in the registerBasicEvents function?

createUniqueId: function (){

and

this.creaIdentificativo()

Comment: You are right, do you think the code is correct?I'll try, maybe i did this error!